# How to connect to a sub-domain FTP in JAVA

Tags: java, windows, apache, ftp

I am trying to write a JAVA program to connect to FTP. I have downloaded .JAR file from apache and added it to LIB folder in my project.

When I try to connect to the FTP as per code below, I get **java.net.UnknownHostException**

If I use

- ftp:// subdomain.example.com - java.net.UnknownHostException
- ftp.subdomain.example.com - java.net.UnknownHostException
- ftp:// example.com - java.net.UnknownHostException
- ftp.example.com - It works!

All my files are at ftp:// subdomain.example.com/ and I don't want to change anything in my FTP.

If I try to open ftp:// subdomain.example.com/ in Google Chrome browser, it asks for my username and password.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.SocketException;

import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;

public class ConnectToFTP {
 public static final void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, IOException {
      FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
      try {
          ftp.connect("ftp://subdomain.example.com"); 
      } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("The Error : " + e.toString());  
      }
      System.out.println("login: "+ftp.login("username", "password"));
 }
}
```

Can you please help me in getting connection to ftp://subdomain.example.com/

Comment: Did you try `ftp://ftp.subdomain.example.com`? I didn't see that on your list.

Comment: I tried it just now and ftp:// ftp.subdomain.example.com gives java.net.UnknownHostException as well... Just to make it clear, there was no space between ftp:// and ftp.subdomain.example.com

Comment: I think you have a misconseption of what a host is and what `ftp://` means. Host is the name of a server i.e. in your case `subdomain.example.com`. `ftp://` is a way for browsers to use a different protocol (by default they use `http://`). So as a host you should use the same value you use in Google Chrome after removing the `ftp://` prefix

Comment: What about subdomain.example.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to use `ftp.connect("subdomain.example.com")`.

Comment: So would you mind marking this as the correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Remove "ftp://"

This line is text is only here so I can submit it.